# Change sidebar after certain scroll

Tags: javascript, sidebar

I am trying to make my sidebar behave as normal, until a certain amount of scroll has happened (it has scrolled past the first child `div` element), and then fix in place.

As a test, I tried just changing it to being blank. But it's not having any affect whatsoever.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var side_offset_top = $('#side').offset().top;
    var side = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > side_offset_top) { 
            document.getElementById('side').innerHTML = ''; //blank to test
        } else {
        }
    };
    side();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        side();
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm new to JavaScript, so I'd appreciate anyone helping me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using jQuery since I see the $

There is an extra `});` on the last line of the code so unless it's a copy paste error you should delete that.

Then try putting the code inside a $(document).ready() handler. $('#side') may not be in the DOM yet when you are checking for it's offset.

Something like (untested):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var side_offset_top = $('#side').offset() && $('#side').offset().top;
    var side = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll_top > side_offset_top) { 
            $('#side').html(''); // using jQuery .html
        }
    };
    side();
    $(window).on('scroll', function() { // consider using .on here instead
        side();
    });
});
```

EDIT: whoops! offset().top() should be offset().top

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work. The two sidebar `div` elements scroll over the top of the fixed nav (horizontal across top), though the `#side` background colour goes behind, as it were.

Comment: I just fixed a bug in the sample code and tested it - the updated version works for me. If I make a div with an ID of side, when the div reaches the top of the window the html is updated